# DateTime.MaxValue saves as Zero in mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, datetime

I am using C# and MySql. I have a requirement where I need to save DateTime.MaxValue to one of the column.

ADO.NET code gives me below value for DateTime.MaxValue

> 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM

When I save this in mysql, I see that the value for that datetime(3) column is saved as:

> 0000-00-00 00:00:00.000

Sample ADO.NET Code

```
DateTime time = DateTime.MaxValue;

sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Expires", time);
sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

DataType of the column is datetime(3)

I still cannot figure it out why DateTime.MaxValue is saved as **0000-00-00 00:00:00.000**

Any thoughts around this?

Comment: It's possible you've exceeded the max datetime value for MySql. Can you try saving the value directly in SQL and see what happens?

Comment: The "zero" value only inserted if the date value is invalid or out-of-range, and `datetime` data type by default supports `DateTime.MaxValue`. Have you tried set explicitly `MySqlDbType.DateTime` for that parameter?

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto I tried to set dbtype as DateTime specifically but didn't throw any exception and saved the data as  0000-00-00 00:00:00.000

Answer (score 4):

A `DATETIME` column can store values [up to `'9999-12-31 23:59:59'`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html). `DateTime.MaxValue` is actually `9999-12-31 23:59:59.9999999`. When you try to insert it, the fractional seconds overflow the maximum size of the field.

Normally (in `STRICT` mode), MySQL Server would issue a `datetime field overflow` error. But if you're running your server in `ANSI` mode, the overflow is silently converted to the "invalid" date time value `0000-00-00`.

One way to fix this problem is to use `STRICT` mode in your MySQL Server.

Another way is to specify the column type as `DATETIME(6)`, which allows the fractional seconds to be stored.

A third way is to truncate the fractional seconds from your `DateTime` objects in C# before inserting them in the database.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe some trigger prevents from saving such a high date to your column?
Have u tried inserting that date from SQL query ?
I did some tests in Oracle DB, and all went smoothly.
It shouldnt be different in mysql ...

Comment: Both Oracle & MySQL datetime supports `DateTime.MaxValue`. I tried in some SQL IDEs and the value inserted smoothly.